# Where can I get information about cabin baggage in Sabre Bargain Finder Max?

Tags: api, soap, sabre

In the documentation for the BaggageProvisionType attribute there is a flag "B", which most likely refers to carry-on baggage, but the response always contains only flag "A" or "C". I'm using soap api.

Answer (score 1):

Carry-on info is available starting from **v6.3.0** of Bargain Finder Max. Here are release notes: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max/release-note

To receive ProvisionType="B" data which stands for carry-on allowances, you have to add `TravelPreferences/Baggage` element to your request (extra nodes are omitted):

```
<TravelPreferences>
          <Baggage RequestType="A" CarryOnInfo="true"/>
</TravelPreferences>
```